# Bind jquery datepicker to dynamic row Textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In HTML table, there is a text field on which I have binded Jquery datepicker control:

```
$("#CreatedOnValue").datepicker();
```

It works fine. The table is dynamic and user can add as many rows as he wants by clicking on add button adjacent to each row. I am trying to bind datepicker control to dynamic rows as well and it is not working. Here is function which is executed when user clicks on row add button:

```
function addGroupRow(e) {
var rowId = e.parentNode.parentNode.id;
var newindex = getConditionPlacementIndex(rowId);

var row = document.getElementById("advancedSearch").insertRow(newindex);

...

// create table cell of datetime textbox
var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
cell3.id = row.id+"_cell3";
var strHtml3 = "<INPUT class=\"textbox\" TYPE=\"text\">";
cell3.innerHTML = strHtml3.replace(/!count!/g, count);
$("#" + cell3.id).datepicker();
}
```

Its not working and datepicker does not appear on dynamic text field. Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by following code modification:

```
var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell3Id = row.id+"_cell3";
var strHtml3 = "<INPUT class=\"textbox\" TYPE=\"text\" id=" + cell3Id + ">";
cell3.innerHTML = strHtml3.replace(/!count!/g, count);
$("#" + cell3Id).datepicker();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` instead of `id`(Give dynamically generated `textboxes` a class say `'textbox'`) and do as :

```
$('body').on('focus',".textbox", function(){
  $(this).datepicker();
});​
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jsc2dbr8/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I really want to get this done by cell ID not Class.